# How to access Mustech template with JS

Tags: javascript, mustache

When the user log in, the user name appears on {{name}} in header.mustache. However, if you try to access userName using JS, a null value appears.
userId: $('#user_id').text() -> Null value. Why is that?

header.mustache

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-lg-4">
                {{#userName}}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <span class="nav-link active" id="user" aria-current="page" id="user_id">{{name}}</span>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/logout" class="nav-link active" role="button">Logout</a>
                </li>
                {{/userName}}
                {{^userName}}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/oauth2/authorization/google" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" >Login</a>
                </li>
                {{/userName}}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/perfume/save" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

index.js

save: function () {

```
    let data = {
        userId: $('#user_id').text(),
        perfumeName: $('#favorite_perfume').val(),
        image: $('#unfavorable_perfume').val()
    };
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/v1/pre',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function () {
        alert('Pass');
        window.location.href = '/';
    }).fail(function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake.

I inserted two id's into span.

before

after

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.